# SQL Query - Trying to figure out Outer Join with three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Schema]

Hi there..above is my database schema which allows me to assign prices to a specific location.  What i want to easily be able to figure out is that when i add a new package my "packagelocationprices" table will be missing entries.  How can i get all of the packages that do not have a location price assigned for all and specific locations.

i had this so far..but it didn't cover other locations that do not have anything in it..how can i adjust this query to take the locations into consideration..

```
SELECT *
FROM Package p
LEFT OUTER JOIN PackageLocationPrices pr ON p.Id = pr.PackageId
Where pr.MonthlyPrice IS NULL
OR pr.TotalPrice IS NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: It would also be helpful to edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  There may be more than one reasonable interpretation of what you are trying to do.  (It is unusual for a question to have 1 deleted answer, much less 4.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the package/location pairs with no prices.  This is a two-step process.  Generate all the package/location pairs and then remove the ones that do have prices.

The first part is a `cross join`.  The second a `left join` with `where` (or similar construct):

```
select p.*, l.*
from package p cross join
     location l left join
     packagelocationprices plp
     on plp.packageid = p.pid and plp.locationid = l.id
where plp.packageid is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you get all the possible combination for packages and locations (cross join). You save that in a Common Table Expression so you can reuse it whenever you want. Even though this is not completely necessary in this example, it gives you more flexibility.

Then, you do a LEFT JOIN with the table PackageLocationPrices, which is a table used for relating packages, locations and set prices. And you pick the records that don't have a row on that table.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT p.Id AS PackageId, l.Id AS LocationId
    FROM Package p
    CROSS JOIN Location l
)
select cte.PackageId, cte.LocationId
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN PackageLocationPrices plp ON cte.PackageId=plp.PackageId AND plp.LocationId=cte.LocationId
WHERE plp.Id IS NULL
```